# Using mustache.js with numbered arrays

Tags: json, mustache

My JSON data source looks like this:

```
{"1":{
    "name":"One",
    "color":"red"
},
{"2":{
    "name":"Two",
    "color":"green"
}
```

I'm trying to loop through these records using mustache.js.

```
var model = [{"1":{"name":"One","color":"red"},{"2":{"name":"Two","color":"green"}];
var template = '<ul> {{#.}} <li>{{name}} -- {{color}} </li> {{/.}} </ul>';
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, model);
console.log(html);
```

But I can't figure out how to access the Name and Color. Any ideas?

Comment: The code clean and simple but the JSON is not.  Naming variables with numbers is never a good thing, although perfectly valid in JS. you could easily remove the "1" and "2" and have your code work as mentioned in the answers below.  If you don't have access to modify the JSON you can prune the model before passing it to mustache as mentioned by d4kris.

Answer (score 1):

```
var model = [ 
             {"1":{"name":"One","color":"red"}},
             {"2":{"name":"Two","color":"green"}}
            ];
var model4view = {dots:
    model.map(function(obj){
        var v; for (k in obj) {v = obj[k];}; return v; })};

template = "'<ul> {{#dots}} <li>{{name}} -- {{color}} </li> {{/dots}} </ul>'";
var html = Mustache.to_html(template, model4view);
```

AFAIK , with reference to the [mustache manual page](http://mustache.github.io/mustache.5.html) **Sections** are the type of tags that allow to render blocks of text **one or more times**, but **The behavior of the section is determined by the value of the key.** so we need a key and a value that is the list. Therefore the array have to be the value of the key.

In the above code I leverage [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
to get a `model4view` which has a **key** with an arbitrary name: `dots` ( so we can use this name in mustache section tag `{{#dots}}` and a **value** that consist of the object value of the original *numberd array* item value. For example:

```
{"dots":[
         {"name":"One","color":"red"},
         {"name":"Two","color":"green"}
        ]}
```

**[EDIT]**
 If you need to output also the numer associated with each item you can use a map function:

```
function(v){
    for (var property in v) { 
      o = v[property];
      o['id'] = property;
      return(o); 
  }});
```

this way the number can be used in the template as `{{id}}`.

[Here is my **fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/rondinif/MdxNU/1/) where you can try and play around the solution.

Comment: Just edit to link the [sample fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rondinif/MdxNU/1/) and show how to preserve the number of the item for the output. I'd report a similar [answered question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13464164/1657028) where ultimately they change how data returns to make **mustache** template work.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if you had your object array like this and use a simple `{{#.}} <li>{{name}} -- {{color}} </li> {{/.}}` loop:

```
var myCars = 
[
{"index":1,"name":"One", "color":"red" }},
{"index":2,"name":"Two", "color":"green" }}
];
```

Another approach is to build an iterator to unwrap each item:

Example here: http://jsfiddle.net/9qMqW/2/

```
var myCars = 
[
{"1":{ "name":"One", "color":"red" }},
{"2":{ "name":"Two", "color":"green" }}
];

// decorate the array with the iterator function
myCars.getNextCar = function(){ 
    !myCars.i ? myCars.i=1 : ++myCars.i;
    return(myCars[myCars.i-1][myCars.i])
};

var template = $("#carsTemplate").html();

$("#carsContainer").html(Mustache.render(template,{cars:myCars}));
```

And your HTML would be:

```
<div id="carsContainer">
    
</div>

<script id="carsTemplate" type="text/plain">
    <ul> 
        {{#cars}} 
            {{#cars.getNextCar}}
            <li>{{name}} -- {{color}}</li>
            {{/cars.getNextCar}}
        {{/cars}}
    </ul>
</script>
```

Note that the method `getNextCar` it will create an iterator in your object so you have to get a fresh one if you're using more than once. Or just change the array contents as other posters suggested.

On a side note, you might want to have a look at http://handlebarsjs.com/ which is a bit more robust with a more flexible syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest possible solution, if you know the keys in your model always look like 1,2,3,...:

```
var model = [{"1":{"name":"One","color":"red"}},{"2":{"name":"Two","color":"green"}}];
var i, len = model.length;
for (i=0; i<len; i++) {
  model[i] = model[i][i+1];
}
```

Note that you're missing the ending curlies on your model.